# "Voting corrected" line item displays "no net reputation changes" message in user profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page

When a user profile shows a large negative reputation change from the "Voting corrected" line item, expanding the item shows the message "There were no net reputation changes on this day" despite the presence of other reputation change line items in the same day. See the below image:

[image: screenshot of reputation tab]

In this case, there is obviously a significant net negative reputation change. It's possible in other cases there could be a net positive reputation change for that day.

If it is impractical to show details about the "4 events" cited in the line item, the next best thing might be to change the message that's shown when you expand the item to indicate that the details are unavailable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks for the report! This will be fixed in the next build.

We don't keep track of which post the reversal applied to once it's been recorded, so the event breakdown can't really be retrieved. With that in mind, we aren't going to show the number of "events" and the expansion arrow anymore and the reversal will simply look like this:

> [image]

Instead of this:

> [image]

Comment: So, let me get this straight: this is a correction of a voting correction?